# How to turn off sorting for Values name in Pandas pivot_table

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I am trying to create a simple pivot table from Pandas pivot_table but I am not able to turn off sorting on the Values name in output table.

Parameter "sort = False" only helps in turning off sorting in Index name.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
"StateName" : ["Manipur", "Manipur", "Assam", "Chennai", "Delhi", "Delhi", "Assam"],
"Male Accounts" : [121, 987, 1043, 34, 209, 89, 90],
"Female Accounts" : [23, 890, 2012, 7810, 765, 902, 23],
"Small Accounts" : [90, 21, 98, 45, 56, 34, 90],
"Current Accounts" : [121, 623, 90, 76, 23, 87, 91]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

pv_table = pd.pivot_table(df, index = "StateName", sort = False, aggfunc = 'sum')
print(pv_table)
```

Output:

```
  StateName  Male Accounts  Female Accounts  Small Accounts  Current Accounts
0   Manipur            121               23              90               121
1   Manipur            987              890              21               623
2     Assam           1043             2012              98                90
3   Chennai             34             7810              45                76
4     Delhi            209              765              56                23
5     Delhi             89              902              34                87
6     Assam             90               23              90                91


           Current Accounts  Female Accounts  Male Accounts  Small Accounts
StateName                                                                  
Manipur                 744              913           1108             111
Assam                   181             2035           1133             188
Chennai                  76             7810             34              45
Delhi                   110             1667            298              90
```

As you can see the Values columns header are getting sorted alphabetically here. Is there anyway to turn off this sorting.

Desired Output:

[image]

Comment: Can’t you just reorder the columns back the way you want them?

Comment: I have big datasets where there are more than 15 values column so I was hoping get it done via code

Comment: TBH does not reorder columns for me.

Comment: Maybe you should update Pandas?

Answer (score 2):

TBH I don't get columns reordered, but you can always change columns to required order:

```py
pv_table = pv_table.reindex(df.columns.drop('StateName'), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems `sort=False` works correctly (new in version 1.3.0, works correctly from 1.5.0):

```
>>> pd.__version__
2.0.1

# Default: sort=True
>>> pd.pivot_table(df, index='StateName', aggfunc='sum')
           Current Accounts  Female Accounts  Male Accounts  Small Accounts
StateName                                                                  
Assam                   181             2035           1133             188
Chennai                  76             7810             34              45
Delhi                   110             1667            298              90
Manipur                 744              913           1108             111

# sort=False
>>> pd.pivot_table(df, index='StateName', aggfunc='sum', sort=False)
           Male Accounts  Female Accounts  Small Accounts  Current Accounts
StateName                                                                  
Manipur             1108              913             111               744
Assam               1133             2035             188               181
Chennai               34             7810              45                76
Delhi                298             1667              90               110
```

Related:

- [What’s new in 1.5.0 (September 19, 2022)](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.5.0.html#reshaping)
- [pivot_table not displaying values columns in expected order](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17041)
- [ENH: do not sort resulting columns when sort=False](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/46994)

Comment: ok. tested on pandas 1.5.3 Sort parameter seems to be working on index as well as value row. Thanks